# Add class to spaces in paragraph using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Below is my Jquery code.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   var listItem = $('#list_id');

    var html = $.trim(listItem.html());

    var count = 0;
    var match = '&nbsp;';

    while (html.substr(0, match.length) === match) {
       count++;
       html = html.substr(count * match.length, (count * match.length) + match.length);
    }

    alert(count);
});
```

I want to find the spaces in a paragraph, and after that add a class to that particular space in the paragraph.

Initially I need to find the spaces. I have tried the code above but its return count is zero. This means it's not found any spaces.

I will use `addClass` to add the class `droppable` to the paragraph inside the textarea.

```
<textarea id="list_id">"Kohl" is considered not only as a cosmetic; the importance of  kohl around eyes dates back to 4000 B.C. when Egyptians used a paste of antimony sulphide and lead sulphide. 
They that it kept the eyes safe from infections, sun rays, and evil spirits. Kohl literally means "something that brightens". So, it was applied around the eyes to draw attention and make them look .</textarea>
```

[image]

From the screenshot.I wanna drag and drop tht choice1 button into textarea anywhere the spaces in textarea.for tht button should be a draggable and Space in textarea should be taken as droppable.From this I wanna define wherevr spaces in paragraph I should declare as droppable so tht I can drag and drop.Thts y Im trying this scenario.Is this possble or Not.

```
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Droppable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #draggable { width: 100px; height: 100px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 10px 10px 10px 0; }
  #droppable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 10px; }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
    $( ".droppable" ).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        /*$( this )
          .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
          .find( "p" )
            .html( "Dropped!" );*/
         $( "#draggable" ).draggable( 'disable' );
      }
    });
  } );
  $( document ).ready(function() {

var listItem = $('#list_id').val().replace(/\ /g, "<div class='droppable'> </div>");

   console.log(listItem);
});
 </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="draggable">
  <p>D</p>
</div>
<textarea id="list_id" class="droppable">"Kohl" is considered not only as a cosmetic; 
the importance of  kohl around eyes dates back to 4000 B.C. when Egyptians used a paste of antimony sulphide and lead sulphide. 
They that it kept the eyes safe from infections, sun rays, and evil spirits. Kohl literally means "something that brightens". So, it was applied around the eyes to draw attention and make them look .</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you trying to put HTML within the value of a `textarea`? As that won't work.

Comment: Do you want to add some markup with a class because you cannot add a class to space it should hold some markup.

Comment: why an earth do you want to do that? :))

Comment: Actually I am developing PTE online test application for that I wanna add fill in the blanks type questions.for that I wanna add blank dash where I want to give as choie 1 for tht purpose Im using

Comment: Okie @aavrug.. Why its not possible we can find the spaces and in general we know how to add class then why its not possble'

Comment: As a final result what you are looking for?

Comment: If I give some paragraph as input in textarea onchange function will calculate spaces and add droppable div class to that space.Thts the result I want

Comment: Just show the exact markup that you want as a final result.

Comment: Like Shall i show screenshot in question

Comment: Whatever easy for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131235/discussion-between-kavya-shree-and-aavrug).

Comment: @KavyaShree you can find all the `spaces` and then wrap it up in a `span` tag and add a class.. will that work for you?

Comment: I tried like that.But from the above code I cnt find space.Will u help me with simple code.

Comment: @KavyaShree see a sample here https://jsfiddle.net/RajReddy/pssrht75/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this just put a condition for checking blank space.

```js
document.getElementById('drag').addEventListener('dragstart', function (e) {
  e.dataTransfer.setData("text", '{' + this.id + '}');
});
```

```html
<p id="drag" href="#" draggable="true">hello</a>

<textarea id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</textarea>
```

Comment: This is not a answer for my question.From your answer I ll tell that drag hello and drop in spaces of that textarea content

Comment: Yea I have added the drag functionality and told you to add just a check do you really want me to do that?

Comment: Its want to check whether there is a space or not after tht only it will drop or else it will revert.Add that part @aavrug

Comment: You told that you want this feature in textarea now you are showing jsfiddle without textarea.

Comment: Anythng is okie @aavrug but the main thng is it will drop only in spaces not inbetween texts

Comment: @KavyaShree See this https://jsfiddle.net/aavrug/k4wpaexq/1/ just updatedyour jsfiddle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131313/discussion-between-kavya-shree-and-aavrug).

Answer (score 0):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   var listItem = $('#list_id').val().replace(/\ /g, "<span class='space'> </span>");

   console.log(listItem);
});
```

This will work, but you should try something else instead of a textarea, you can try a contentEditable div...

### Edit

---

I don't know if this is what you want to achieve, but here is a working fiddle with basic concepts, this is the initial idea...

https://jsfiddle.net/caiokawasaki/d07pvbe3/

Comment: See the below code.I will try as ur idea but If I drop tht place it will overlap the already typed word..See the above code.

Comment: Ya.Thts great this is what exactly I want.

Comment: Now you already know where to start, good luck =) Accept my response if it helped...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131248/discussion-between-kavya-shree-and-caio-kawasaki).

Comment: Before its worked now its not drop in space..Is there any library missed

Comment: I tested tht part if I drag and drop It will drop even in text between.Can we add constraint If I try to drop on text it will revert if it between space it will drop

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
<title>jQuery UI Droppable - Default functionality</title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/jquery-ui.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css"> 
<style> 
.draggable{
  display: inline-block;
}

#list_id .space{
    background-color: transparent;
    border:1px dashed #ccc;
    padding: 3px 40px;
  }
</style> 
<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script> 
 <script src="assets/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script> 
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.draggable').draggable({
        revert: 'invalid',
        stop: function(){
            $(this).draggable('option','revert','invalid');
        }
    });

    $('.draggable').droppable({
       greedy: true,
        tolerance: 'touch',
       drop: function(event,ui){
           ui.draggable.draggable('option','revert',true);
       }
    });
  var listItem = $('#list_id');

  function replaceSpaces(){
    return listItem.text().replace(/\ /g, "<span class='space'> </span>")
  }

  $('#list_id').on("blur", function(){
    $("#list_id").html(replaceSpaces());
    $("#list_id_input").val(replaceSpaces());



    $(".space").droppable({
     accept: ".draggable",
     drop: function(event, ui) {        
       console.log(event.target);
       $(this).append($(ui.draggable));
       $(ui.draggable).removeAttr("style");
     },
    });
  });
});
</script> 
</head> 
<body> 
<div class="draggable">Choice1</div><br/><br/>
<div id="list_id" contentEditable>"Kohl" is considered not only as a cosmetic; the importance of  kohl around eyes dates back to 4000 B.C. when Egyptians used a paste of antimony sulphide and lead sulphide. 
They that it kept the eyes safe from infections, sun rays, and evil spirits. Kohl literally means "something that brightens". So, it was applied around the eyes to draw attention and make them look .</div>
<input type="hidden" id="list_id_input">
</body> 
</html>
```